# Middleman and I18n: having some issues

Tags: middleman, i18n-gem

I have activated I18n in middleman like so:

```
activate :i18n, mount_at_root: :de
```

Now I'd like to be redirected from `/` to `/de` automatically. Is this possible?

Also, I wonder why middleman auto-assigns class `index` (for german) and `en_index` (for english) using the `page_classes` helper? This doesn't make much sense - it's the same page, so it should use the class `index` for both english and german. Or did I miss something?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you `:mount_at_root => :de` german will be your default language and thus *not* prefixed.

If you set `:mount_at_root => :false` all languages should be prefixed.

I have successfully used the following configuration to set `de/en` paths.

This will also create `page_classes` such as as `en en_index` and `de de_index`.

```
activate :i18n, :mount_at_root => :false, :langs => [:de, :en]
```

http://middlemanapp.com/advanced/localization/

Redirecting from `/` to `/de` is done using `redirect "index.html", :to => "de/index.html"`.

To prevent `page_classes` from prefixing the classes with the language, overwrite the helper like so:

```
helpers do
  def page_classes(path=current_path.dup, options={})
    super(path.sub(/^[a-z]{2}\//, ''), options)
  end
end
```

Comment: I guess you don't need to explicitly set `path: ":locale"`, it seems to be default.

Comment: Yes, that might be true. Beside of that, was the answer helpful to you?

Comment: I updated the answer. Now it can be marked as correct. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks, the edit is fine with me. I misread the second part of your question and didn't notice that you wanted to get rid of the language prefix in the body classes.